# Add an import button to an admin module

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I want to add an import button to an admin module. Essentially all it needs to do is bring up a file viewer and let the user select the file to run calculations on.

Do I need to declare the button in the template file? If so how do I refernce it from the block? OR do I add the button via the block only?

I'm fairly new to Magento and just trying to get my feet wet.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. It would be easier to help you if you shared what you have so far and what exactly you need help with. Is it an existing module? What's "the template" and "the block" you are talking about? As it stands, I could answer: "add `<input type="file">` to the template and you are done." but this wouldn't really help...

Comment: @fschmengler I think I might have a solution posted below. It is a bit, ehm, creative however

Comment: No idea if this solves OPs problem, but it's a nice trick regardless.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a button to the admin in the construct of the class that also updates the **add** button in the grid.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Blockname] extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller         = 'adminhtml_action';
        $this->_blockGroup         = '[block namespace]';
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_updateButton('add', 'label', 'Add item'); // THIS updates the button
    }
}
```

The `_addButton` method accepts a couple of arguments: `$id`, `$date`, `$level`, `$sortOrder`, `$area`. We'll only use the first two.

But first lets take a look at how the button is rendered by block class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Button` with the following method

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $html = $this->getBeforeHtml().'<button '
        . ($this->getId()?' id="'.$this->getId() . '"':'')
        . ($this->getElementName()?' name="'.$this->getElementName() . '"':'')
        . ' title="'
        . Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getTitle() ? $this->getTitle() : $this->getLabel())
        . '"'
        . ' type="'.$this->getType() . '"'
        . ' class="scalable ' . $this->getClass() . ($this->getDisabled() ? ' disabled' : '') . '"'
        . ' onclick="'.$this->getOnClick().'"'
        . ' style="'.$this->getStyle() .'"'
        . ($this->getValue()?' value="'.$this->getValue() . '"':'')
        . ($this->getDisabled() ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '')
        . '><span><span><span>' .$this->getLabel().'</span></span></span></button>'.$this->getAfterHtml();

    return $html;
}
```

The variables called here can be set by added them in the 2th variable `$data` when calling `_addButton`.

Since you want a file upload we'll need to get a bit fancy, specially with the `$data` array. It would look something like this.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Blockname] extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller         = 'adminhtml_action';
        $this->_blockGroup         = '[block namespace]';
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_updateButton('add', 'label', 'Add item'); // THIS updates the button

        $this->_addButton('import', array(
            'label'         => Mage::helper('[namespace]_[module]')->__('Import'),
            'onclick'       => 'document.getElementById(\'uploadTarget\').click();',
            'class'         => 'add',
            'after_html'    => '<form method="POST" action="[your module url that handles upload]" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
            <input type="file" name="importfile" style="display:none;" id="uploadTarget"/>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById(\'uploadTarget\').addEventListener(\'change\', function(){
            document.getElementById(\'uploadForm\').submit();
        }, false);
        </script>',
        ));
    }
}
```

Basically this injects a form with file input type after your button but hides it.

Clicking the **import** button would trigger the upload field and displaying the file browser. When the file type input is changed (i.e. you picked a file) the form would submit to an URL of your liking.

**--> DISCLAIMER <--**

I did not test this so please don't just throw this in your live shop. Test it, it might need some tender love and tweaking

*[UPDATE]*
Many thanks to @Marius for pointing out the missing formkey